# Export to excel is exporting check box to excel instead of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview

```
GridView grdExgratia = new GridView();
DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["DataSet"];

try
{
    if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        grdExgratia.DataSource = ds;
        grdExgratia.DataBind();

        for (int i = 0; i < grdExgratia.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridItem dataItem = dgExgratia.Items[i];
            CheckBox chkApprove = (CheckBox)dataItem.FindControl("chkApprove");
            Label lblB_FLAG = (Label)dataItem.FindControl("lblB_FLAG");

            if (chkApprove.Enabled== true)
            {
                lblB_FLAG.Text = "Paid";
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= Exgratia_Employees.xls");
        grdExgratia.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
        Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Above is the code I am using for export to excel. But while exporting data the last column is B_FLAG which is of BIT data type in database is getting converted into check box. While showing data in grid view it is rendering as TRUE and FALSE. Can any one please help me to export text value to excel instead of checkbox.

Comment: Check the name of your control

Comment: @reds I checked still not working. Can you please suggest any other way.

Comment: Your StringWriter strwritter doesn't have any relation to your for loop, you don't have any StringBuilder also..

Answer (score 0):

because you render grid to excel if you want to make it to true or false you should get datasource and manipulate your data. For instance, add new row for "true" and "false" based on your "chkApprove" bool value and then export.